# root resource classes scanning pattern of Jersey framework

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-1.0

I have created sample project in eclipse and deployed it in tomcat.

I am using below jar files.

asm-3.1.jar

jersey-core-1.10.jar

jersey-server-1.10.jar

jersey-servlet-1.10.jar

below are classes.

```
package example;  

import javax.ws.rs.GET;  
import javax.ws.rs.Path;  
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;  


@Path("helloworld")  
public class HelloWorldResource {  

    @GET  
    @Produces("text/plain")  
    public String getHello() {  
        return "Hello World!";  
    }  

}
```

and

```
package example;  

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;  
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;  


@ApplicationPath("/")  
public class MyApplication extends Application {  
//    @Override  
//    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {  
//        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();  
//        // register root resource  
//        classes.add(HelloWorldResource.class);  
//        return classes;  
//    }  
}
```

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app>  
  <display-name>JXRSHelloWorld</display-name>  
    <servlet>    
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>    
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>   
</web-app>
```

My Doubts

1. How does Jersey framework inject/scan JAX-RS resources. if we don't provide class names explicitly
2. Some docs says (links are provided below), we have to explicitly register package name to tell Jersey framework so it can scan those packages and inject AX-RS resources.

Link 1 : https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.2

Link 2 : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ggnxs/index.html

even if I remove method getClasses() from class MyApplication, It is working fine. My doubt is how does it finds resource HelloWorldResource.java ?

This is my Tomcat’s catalina.out logfile's snap:

```
Feb 6, 2014 7:48:38 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses  
INFO: Root resource classes found:  
  class example.HelloWorldResource
```

**In above code I do not explicitly tell framework to register my class HelloWorldResource as I have commented getClasses method.
Does it scan by annotation like @Path("helloworld") @Produces("text/plain") ?**

Thanks,

Niraj